# How to provide pemfile password in pymongo mongoclient in the connection string

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

Question: How to provide pemfile password in pymongo mongoclient in the connection string?

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

    sslCAFile = data['COMMON_SETTINGS']['sslCAFile']  //reading cafile path from configurationfile
    sslpemkeyfile = data['COMMON_SETTINGS']['sslpemkeyfile'] //reading pemfile path from configurationfile(which is encrypted with password)
```

// now i need to connect by giving the password . but i dont see any parameter for that in pymongo documentation and in authentication examples

```
    connection = 
    MongoClient(mongos_ip,int(mongos_port),ssl=True,ssl_certfile=sslpemkeyfile,ssl_ca_certs=sslCAFile)
```

//Help me on this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the current version of pymongo doesn't support this feature

**ref:** https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-640

Comment: Right, fundamentally it's a limitation in Python.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
import ssl

connection = MongoClient(mongos_ip, int(mongos_port),
                         ssl=True,
                         ssl_certfile=sslpemkeyfile,
                         ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                         ssl_ca_certs=sslCAFile)
```

It is from here: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/authentication.html

Comment: @Petersen If you do like that, the program will still ask for sslPemKey password. I think the user needs to bypass this step.

Comment: Yes.. I need to bypass the password step . its asking me each and every time . is there any provision for it in Mongoclient method.

Comment: In NodeJs we have something like this right ..var fs =require('fs');

var cert= fs.readFileSync("/etc/ssl/mongod_server.crt");
var key = fs.readFileSync("/etc/ssl/mongod_server.key");


var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:10027/test',{server : {ssl:true,sslKey:key,sslCert:cert,sslPass:'12345'}});

Comment: In this we can bypass the password step .. so iam askin is there any like that in pymongo

Comment: There is an username/password option in the connection URI mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]. Maybe that will work? MongoClient can take an URI instead of addr and port: pymongo.MongoClient(uri, ssl=True, ssl_certfile=...)

Comment: @Petersen That username/password is for logging into database .. not related to SSL_pem_file_password . :(